# Show AlertDialog when the property Maxlenght a EditText are exceeded

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

What I want to do now, is to bring up a dialog box, when you exceed the character insertion of EditText, maxlenght set as "15" in the XML file, after which the user can continue to press on the keyboard but to no avail of course, and I would then bring up the dialog box (AlertDialog) indicating that the user has exceeded the limit of characters entered.

I show you the methods created, the action to send the message, the AlertDialog for a control, and the AlertDialog for the limit characters

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String messaggio = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, messaggio);
    if (messaggio.equals("")) {
        finestraInfo();
    }else {
        startActivity(intent); 
        editText.setText("");
    }
}

//AlertDialog message empty
public void finestraInfo() {
    AlertDialog.Builder info = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    info.setTitle("Info");
    info.setMessage("Empty message, enter message!");
    info.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    info.create().show();
}

//AlerDialog limited
public void infoLimiteParole(){
    AlertDialog.Builder info = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    info.setTitle("Info");
    info.setMessage("Character limit exceeded.!");
    info.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    info.create().show();
}
```

How can I make interact the EditText (id = edit_message) with The AlertDialog? On what I could build a verification check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once try as follows

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(s.toString().length()>15)
                infoLimiteParole();
        }
    });
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: This solution seems to give some problems, seemed to work, but does not always work, the alertDilog not always appears. It could be a problem of the method infoLimiteParole ()? 
EDIT 
If control if (s.toString (). Length ()> 15) it imposed in beforeTextChanged, I get that when I press the button "Send Message", seems to appear quickly, the message that the method infoLimiteParole (), after which, returning to the first Activity, when I write in the EditText, and overcome the characters set, then the method appears AlerDialog inforLimiteParole.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **TextWatcher** via EditText's **addTextChangedListener()** method.

```
EditText myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
myText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        if (s.length() > n)
        {
           // Show Dialog that limit is exceeded
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
});
```